# climatic data from MODIS or other sources

Tags: data, remote-sensing, modis, climate, precipitation

I'm looking for climatic information in the form of raster like MODIS daily LST (Land Surface Temperature) data. I'm looking for other parameters like precipitation, humidity, air pressure and so on. Does anybody have information where could I find MODIS (or other sources) data for these parameters and what is the best choice for each?

Comment: Very very vague question - almost any data set fits to it! You need to specify more: Do you need to see how this parameters vary in time, or you just want long-term average? What time and space resolution do you need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [PRISM](http://www.prism.oregonstate.edu/) Climate Group's data is exceptional.  Their raster products include precipitation, max temp, min temp, dewpoint and historic data.

NASA's [MODIS](http://modis.gsfc.nasa.gov/data/dataprod/index.php) site has a wealth of data as does this [USGS](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/products/modis_products_table) site.  You will find a wide range of products there from vegetation indices to emissivity and burn data.

Answer (score 4):

for rainfall you can download the TRMM datasets: http://trmm.gsfc.nasa.gov/

Answer (score 4):

The [WorldClim dataset](http://www.worldclim.org/formats) has a lot of the data you want. It is free for non-commercial use and has interpolated 1 km resolution data on:

- average monthly mean temperature (°C * 10)
- average monthly minimum temperature (°C * 10)
- average monthly maximum temperature (°C * 10)
- average monthly precipitation (mm)

Comment: +1 WorldClim is a great source and well documented dataset.

Answer (score 1):

If you still need TRMM data there is a new QGIS plugin that allows you to download the 3B42 product. You can download the original data, with a 3 hours frequency, but you can also aggregate it in daily layers. The data is available from January 1st 1998 to July 31st 2015. You can browse the plugin page here:  https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/geobricks_qgis_plugin_trmm/